# IGuru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited) - How to Resolve?

Tags: python, esp32, arduino-esp32

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I'm encountering a "Guru Meditation Error" while processing an audio file on my system. The error message indicates that "Core 1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited)" and provides some register dump and backtrace information. I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue. [serial monitor out put] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWK6E.png)

I was trying to build a voice accessible chat GPT using esp32, with i2s INMP441 mic as input
i was trying to replicate the project in this link https://youtu.be/gGcskjKtArU?feature=shared

Answer (score 0):

above the "Guru meditation Error" line, you should see a line "backtrace: 0x..... 0x....". It tells you which lines in your code causes the issue.
You can use addr2line tool like this solution [here](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/6567#issuecomment-1019942513) for debugging.
For example: /PATH/TO/ADDR2LINE.exe -e /PATH/TO/BUILD/.ELF 0x.. 0x.. (the backtrace line).
You have to generate the output build to have the elf file.